# How does C# evaluate lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda, evaluation, lambda-calculus

I've been reading a bit about algorithms for evaluating lambda calculus (not parsing but just evaluating after is parsed), but so far all of them seem the kind of method you'd use with a pen and paper. I'd like to write my own lambda calculus evaluator in C# from scratch and would like to know how an actual program would do this.

Since lambda expressions are a superset of lambda calculus, I'd like to know how the lambda calculus subset of the lambda expressions are evaluated (don't care about binary operations or casting, etc.).

I already have my classes but I'm not sure how to go from here to evaluating:

```
public enum TermType { Variable, Application, Abstraction };

public abstract class LambdaTerm
{
    public readonly TermType TermType;

    protected LambdaTerm(TermType termType)
    {
        TermType = termType;
    }
}

public class LambdaVariable : LambdaTerm
{
    public string Name;
    public LambdaVariable() : base(TermType.Variable) { }
}

public class LambdaApplication : LambdaTerm
{
    public LambdaTerm Function;
    public LambdaTerm Parameter;
    public LambdaApplication() : base(TermType.Application) { }
}

public class LambdaAbstraction : LambdaTerm
{
    public string ArgumentName;
    public LambdaTerm Body;
    public LambdaAbstraction() : base(TermType.Abstraction) { }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting in an answer here?

Comment: @AustinSalonen What do you mean? Isn't my question clear enough? I want to know, roughly at least, what kind of algorithm is used to evaluate lambda expressions.

Comment: This question might do better over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CDspace I though about it but programmers who deeply understands C# mechanisms are most likely to know what algorithm is used to evaluate lambda expressions.

Comment: I think you're looking for a lexical analyzer generator and a parser generator (ex: lex, yacc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda expressions are not related to lambda calculus. The notation is similar, the semantics - completely different.

In fact, C# lambda expressions are just shorter forms of function. A chain of lambdas is in fact a chain of methods. What happens to it, depends on the context.

Instead of searching for analogies, just write a standard lambda calculus interpreter, following the semantic rules. This should be easy academic level task.

Comment: As far as I understand, you can turn any lambda calculus expression into a C# lambda expression (in C# you have variables, application and abstraction). So the ability to evaluate C# lambda expressions imply the ability to evaluate lambda calculus. If lambdas are methods, then I guess turning lambdas into C# methods (whatever C# methods are) is a method for evaluating lambda calculus and is a potential answer to my question. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you think of **typed** lambda calculus then you could at least try. However, untyped lambda calculus will not fit into C# lambdas.